# Why is clipboard UIPasteboardChanged notification fired twice?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, clipboard, nsnotificationcenter

I subscribed for clipboard text change notification. Every time something is copied into he clipboard in my app, it fires the event twice. In other words onCopy() is called twice. (xCode 8.1; iOS 9, 10)

```
import Foundation

protocol Clipboard {
    func onCopy()
}

class SecureClipboard : NSObject, Clipboard {
    static let sharedReader = SecureClipboard()
    private var clipboardContent: String?
    private var clipboardBeingCleared: Bool = false

    /// Lifycycle

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        subscribForClipboardChanges()
    }

    private func subscribForClipboardChanges() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(onCopy),
                                               name:NSNotification.Name.UIPasteboardChanged,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    /// Clipboard

    func onCopy() {
        // Called twice
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you subscribed two times? maybe `self` is constructed twice?

Comment: @DanielKrom I inserted the entire class I use. It's very simple. The  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver is only called once.

Comment: Is you ViewController containing the action for this notification presented inside a uinavigationcontroller?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

It sends back notifications with info about how the pasteboard contents have changed, such as Added or Removed events. It does trigger twice for me for each pasteboard change events, but the user info it contains is different each time.

I debounced a short duration to ignore these, because I do not need any information contained in the notification's userInfo, otherwise, you could try to parse the contents and figure out exactly which ones you care about.

```
NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIPasteboard.changedNotification)
        .debounce(for: .milliseconds(100), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
```

Comment: Debouncing risks losing important info. Your 2nd option of checking the notification's userInfo is the far better approach.

Comment: @HangarRash Fair point. I don't need anything in the user info and I updated my answer to reflect this.